# How do I change the text of a label with a segmented controller that has three segments>

Tags: swift, xcode

For class I have a segmented controller that has three segments.
First segment: make label say Hello
Second segment make label say goodbye
Third segment make label say you rock.
I also need to add a name entered by a text field and when a button is pushed it goes into the label either starting with Hello, Goodbye, or You Rock.[The picture is showing what I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsjE7.png)
[second picture shows what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQXxy.png)

Comment: This is a homework assignment. You are supposed to be learning. If we write your code for you, that’s not learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title of the selected segment and insert it into the name label text.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var greetingControl: UISegmentedControl!

    // MARK: Properties

    var name: String? {
        return nameTextField.text
    }

    var greeting: String? {
        return greetingControl.titleForSegment(
            at: greetingControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        )
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    private func updateOutlets() {
        nameLabel.text = "\(greeting!), \(name!)!"
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func changeNameOnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        updateOutlets()
    }

    @IBAction func nameController(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        updateOutlets()
    }
}
```